# The influence of the derived subgroup of the unit group of a group algebra

Tags: gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, group-rings, group-algebras

Let $FG$ be a group algebra in which $K$ is a field and $G$ is a group. Suppose that every element in the derived subgroup $\mathcal{U}(FG)'$ of the unit group $\mathcal{U}(FG)$ of $FG$ is a multiplicative commutator.

> **Question.** Is the structure of $FG$ or $G$ or $F$ affected?

For instance, I wonder if this assumption can imply that $G$ is a toison group or how the derived length is. Moreover, do you know anything about the influence of the derived subgroup of the unit group of a group algebra on the whole structure?

Any counterexample or reference is very much appreciated. Thank you in advance.